# Python logging: override log time

Tags: python, logging, time, simulation, milliseconds

Following [Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatTime), I'm trying to override `logging.Formatter.converter` in order to control the time logged.
As you can see below - **the milliseconds were not overriden** (they are the current time milliseconds).

How come? How can I control the milliseconds as well?

```
>>> import logging, datetime
>>> formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(message)s')
>>> handler = logging.StreamHandler()
>>> handler.setFormatter(formatter)
>>> def sim_time(t):
...     return datetime.datetime(2000,1,2,3,4,5,678).timetuple()
...
>>> formatter.converter = sim_time
>>> log = logging.getLogger('test')
>>> log.addHandler(handler)
>>> log.info('hi')
2000-01-02 03:04:05,898:hi
>>> log.info('hi')
2000-01-02 03:04:05,914:hi
>>> log.info('hi')
2000-01-02 03:04:05,434:hi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override `logging.Formatter.formatTime()` instead with this:

```
def sim_time(record, datefmt=None):
    return datetime.datetime(2000,1,2,3,4,5,678).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')[:-3]

formatter.formatTime = sim_time
```

If you need it for all loggers in this process, you can override the class function itself, but do this right after the first `import logging` statement your code encounters:

```
def sim_time(self, record, datefmt=None):
    return datetime.datetime(2000,1,2,3,4,5,678).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')[:-3]

import logging
logging.Formatter.formatTime = sim_time
```

Answer (score 1):

`timetuple()` doesn't use milliseconds, so that the ms information contained in the datetime object is lost once the method is called:

```
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 678)
>>> d.timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2000, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=3, tm_min=4, tm_sec=5, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=2, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Note that this is not a limitation of this particular method, but rather of the [`time.struct_time` type](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.struct_time).

The bottom line is: if you need to override the timestamp, don't pass through a `time.struct_time` object. You could - for example - pass the timestamp already formatted as a string, rather than a fake time. Depending on your needs there might be better methods, of course!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better example that allows you to replace the time that was generated, as the accepted answer didn't really do that.

```
def inSimulatedTime(self,secs=None):
    global myTimeKeeper
    try:
       ts=myTimeKeeper.getCurrentTimeLocal() # returns a datetime.datetime object
       return ts.timetuple()
except Exception as e:
    #sometimes my timekeeper hasn't been initialized yet.
    return time.localtime(secs)
```

To enable it:

```
logging.Formatter.converter=inSimulatedTime
```