# Is there a way to configure a Python logging formatter via config file to log time as Unix timestamp?

Tags: python, logging, configuration-files

I'm writing a central `logging` configuration file for a dozen or so Python components and I need one specific logger to log time in the UNIX time format (either milliseconds or seconds with fractions, both is good).

Is there a way to configure a formatter in the config file, to output `%(asctime)s` like that? I'm trying to avoid having to monkey-patch a Formatter instance in multiple independent Python scripts, and it's unfeasible to post-process the log-file.

Related: [Python logging: override log time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376626/python-logging-override-log-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add

```
datefmt = %s
```

to your corresponding formatter config section or formatter constructor call, e.g.:

```
[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %s
```

See also [`logging.Formatter`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter) constructor and [strftime(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime).

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I know it looks like it should work, but I get `ValueError: Invalid format string` (only) when I use the small `%s`.

Comment: Yes, works perfectly for me. See minimal working example here: https://gist.github.com/1819970

Comment: Bah. `time.strftime` fails as described on Windows and I could confirm your solution on Linux. Apparently, Python's strftime is [documented](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) as not having `%s`, so it's effectively an undocumented platform-specific feature...

Comment: If you really need that on windows, you could consider monkey-patching `time.strftime`. `%s` is apparently supported on Linux, FreeBSD and MacOS X, but apparently it is missing on Windows and Solaris.

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to answer the original question (as posed) to give milliseconds since epoch (or seconds+fraction). It only gives seconds since epoch. Is there a variant where I could actually get milliseconds since the epoch?

Answer (score 4):

I have just found the following solution:

```
import logging

class UnixTimeStampFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt = None):
        return "{0:.6f}".format(record.created)

def main():
    logChannel = logging.StreamHandler()
    logChannel.setFormatter(UnixTimeStampFormatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s"))
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(logChannel)
    logging.debug('hello');

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to do something like this, because I have many independent, no-code-shared scripts that need to log the time in the asked fashion.

Answer (score 3):

The [LogRecord object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) has the attribute `created` which is used as basis for the `asctime` and is already in the format you want (seconds with fractions). The easiest solution therefore might be to replace all occurrences of `%(asctime)s` in the format strings with `%(created)f`:

```
[formatter_generic]
format = %(created)f %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
```